# A Class to store Students Classes?

Tags: php, class, reserved-words

So.. i'm working on a system where I will store the data about my students classes (name, code, location and etc)

The problem is: **Class is a reserved word!**

And I don't want to do on my last version where I called it "MyClass".

So, any advice on this naming issue?

Comment: you don't have to use English words whey not use the Portuguese word for class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using "Course" instead.

Comment: What would you call courses then?

Comment: OP didn't indicate he needed to make that particular distinction, but assuming for a second he did: One popular route is to spell class with a "k" (`Klass`) and this would free the term "course" to be used as the name for a `Course` class.